# pied-piping in relative clauses

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses, pied-piping

Are the following relative clauses correct?

> 1. This is the house which I fixed the door of.
> 2. This is the house of which I fixed the door.
> 3. This is the house the door of which I fixed.
> 4. This is the house of I fixed the door.
> 5. This is the house the door of I fixed.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Some of your reasoning as to why these might not be correct could help us understand your question better.  Also, I don't see the connection between these questions and the pied-piper.

Comment: @JamesK - Look up [pied-piping](https://www.thoughtco.com/pied-piping-syntax-1691627).

Comment: Verifying/correcting examples, without specifying the underlying grammar issue of concern, is proofreading. Reordering words or phrases may be valid, but for what reason?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing has no "correct" answer. All you can do is collect opinions of native speakers and make up hypotheses to explain them. Anyway, as a native speaker, I'll give you my opinions:

1. This is the house which I fixed the door of. (pretty good)
2. This is the house of which I fixed the door. (mediocre)
3. This is the house the door of which I fixed. (not good)
4. This is the house of I fixed the door. (really bad)
5. This is the house the door of I fixed. (really bad)

Bonus for completeness: This is the house I fixed the door of. (pretty good)

Comment: I have to disagree. *This is the house the door of I fixed* is grammatical and is not in the same category as #4, which is gibberish.  *This is the girl the sister of I went to the dance with.*

Comment: You're welcome to disagree. These are just my opinions. My opinion is that "This is the girl the sister of I went to the dance with." is also really bad.

Comment: What is considered most formally correct there is #3.

Comment: @PaulDexter I agree with your opinion except for 3) and that the examples with "this is the x the y of + conjugated verb are examples for the game buzzer. I still say that one normally would not use any of these awkward constructions and that the construction asked about is a typical French construction. An "of which" construction in English is either very formal or rather high register. And no contractor or handyman would use it (door fixers}, unless they had missed their vocation as a (9th century) novel writer.

Comment: Like 3) would be; This is the man of  whom I spoke. This is the car of which I trashed the engine. [grammatical but truly awful in English, sounds French]. This car has the engine I trashed, not the one in the junkyard.

Comment: It will be easier to keep track of everyone's opinions if those with different opinions than me will post your own answers in a similar format as mine. Then we can compare everyone's opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what you may have been told or taught (in some cases, quite vehemently) there is no actual rule that you can't end a sentence with a preposition.  To quote [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with):

> In the 18th century, a number of people who liked telling other people that they were wrong ... began advising against the terminal preposition. Sometimes, the advice was to not end a sentence with a preposition ... Noah Webster, in his 1784 book on grammar, took care to advise against separating prepositions "from the words which they govern." He did allow that "grammarians seem to allow of this mode of expression in conversation and familiar writings, but it is generally considered inelegant, and in the grave and sublime styles, is certainly inadmissible."
>
> However, by the time the 20th century rolled around most grammar and usage guides had come to the conclusion that there was really nothing wrong with terminal prepositions. In fact, there has been, for about 100 years now, near unanimity in this regard from usage guides.

As in your examples, all too often, in avoiding the terminal preposition, sentences end up being more convoluted and less comprehensible, such as with Winston Churchill's oft-quoted retort,

> This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put.

Still, this does not mean ending with a preposition is the best way to write a sentence.  For instance, in your example why not just say:

> I fixed the door **of this house**.

or, if you must:

> This is the house **whose** door I fixed.

Still, where's the fun in that?  If we were to embrace this so called rule, then really the only option that won't leave you with a permanently sprained tongue would be:

> This is the house the door of which I fixed.

Of course, you can use this same pattern with similar sentences:

> This is the book the introduction of which I can not understand.
>
> That is the cat the howls of which keep me up at night
>
> [These are the men the souls of which these times try.](http://www.ushistory.org/paine/crisis/c-01.htm)

and so on.

Comment: I have reread your answer and I agree with the way  you logically presented the options. Sure, end a sentence with a preposition but please note: we would tend to say: This cat's howling is what keeps me up at night. This book's  introduction is what I cannot understand. One thing is grammar, another is likelihood; This is the house the door of which I fixed is grammatically right but who would actually say that or even write it? So why not: This house's door is the one I fixed?